# Function not Inserting Values in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function name_to_match($nametocheck){
    global $wpdb,$namematch,$nomatchfound;
    $query="select * from currency";
    $namematch=$wpdb->get_col($query,1);
    //echo $namematch;
        foreach($namematch as $namet){
            //echo $name;
            if($namet == $nametocheck){
                echo "Name Already Exists<br />";
                $nomatchfound=0;
            }

        }
}

function add_signal_form(){
    global $wpdb,$insert,$nametocheck;
    echo "<br /><br /><br />";
    $nametocheck=trim($_POST['name']);
    $sign=trim($_POST['sign']);
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //..................Function to call if name exist it will not add 
name_to_match($nametocheck);

        if($nomatchfound ==0){
            echo "Match Found";}
else
{

            $insert= $wpdb->insert('currency',array('name'=>$nametocheck,'sign'=>$sign,'status'=>$status));
                if(!$insert){
                    echo "Currency Not Added Query Fails";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Currency Successfully Added";
                }       
    }
 }

    echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">';
    echo '<div class="label">';
    echo '<label for="name">Name</label>';
    echo '<div class="field">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="name" id="name">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="label">';
    echo '<label for="sign">Sign</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="field">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="sign" id="sign">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="label">';
    echo '<label for="status">Status</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="field">';
    echo '<select name="status" id="status">';
    echo '<option value="1">Publish</option>';
    echo '<option value="0">Draft</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="submit">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Currency">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</form>';
/*
    echo "<form action='' name=form1\" id=\"form1\" method=\"post\">";
    echo '<input type="text" name="text" id="text">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Signal">';  
        //wp_dropdown_pages();
    echo "</form>";
*/}
```

This function working properly if name exist it return exists but when it not exist nothing happen no else clause fire what is the problem. I am doing something wrong . i want after checking it submit the form and show success message when currency added but nothing happening i try whole the day long and at last i fails in it suggest me

Comment: Is there any point where you set `$nomatchfound` to `true` or `1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @akirk suggested, you're never setting `$nomatchfound` to `true` or `1` in your `name_to_match` function.

But there are some other things you could do to make the code clearer and quicker.  For example, `name_to_match` could return a value, instead of setting a global variable.  And you could use the database to check for `$nametocheck`, rather than looping over all the values in the table - it'll make your code shorter and it'll run quicker.  So I'd change `name_to_match` to something like this:

```
function name_to_match($nametocheck){
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare("select count(*) from currency where name = %s", $nametocheck);
    $matching_row_count = $wpdb->get_var($query);

    return $matching_row_count;
}
```

Then the start of your `add_signal_form` function becomes

```
function add_signal_form(){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<br /><br /><br />";
    $nametocheck=trim($_POST['name']);
    $sign=trim($_POST['sign']);
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $existing_rows = name_to_match($nametocheck);

        if($existing_rows != 0){
            echo "Match Found";
        }
        else {

            $insert= $wpdb->insert('currency',array('name'=>$nametocheck,'sign'=>$sign,'status'=>$status));
            if (!$insert) {
                echo "Currency Not Added Query Fails";
            }
            else {
                    echo "Currency Successfully Added";
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: No +1 is enable for me ... but thanks alot i learned prepare statement too from you...

Comment: Glad to help.  If you can't +1, can you accept the answer (the big check mark)?  As the asker, you should be able to, and that gives me reputation like an upvote.  Cheers